# No sound after few second by playing youtube video

Tags: sound, video, youtube

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 with asus laptop with Intel sound driver.
Ubuntu recognize laptop sound as internal speaker ,and sound response bar is working.

However, the sound stopped after starting YouTube within few sound.

Unusually, last one speaker stopped work after other speaker stopped work within one second while the sound response bar is still working